# Preventing PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown from affect parent, on specific child

Tags: wpf, events, wpf-controls, mouseevent

I have 2 buttons:

```
<Button Name="parent">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="a" />
        <Button Name="b" />
        <Button Name="c" />
        <Button Name="d" />
        <Button Name="e" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Parent is registered to `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event. 
I want that the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event of the parent will not happen if we click on button `c` (`c` has some other registrations). I can't check it specifically (with GetPosition or to register to MouseEnter on `c` and change some flag...), because the `parnet` is generic one, and can contain many buttons.

I've tried to register `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` in `c`, but `e.Handled = true` isn't helping me, because the parent's event occurs before the child's one.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown  uses a tunneling strategy , it hits the child last and the parent first ,

it sound like you need  MouseLeftButtonDown in this case which uses a bubbling strategy and apply

```
     e.IsHandled = true
```

when handling it from c  ,

FYI ,for this reason  e.IsHandled effects only child elements of you Button .

see [RoutedEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)